# Not able to assign datasource value in angular

Tags: angular, material-design, angular-material

[image]    constructor(private appService: AppService) { }
      newHero:putDetail
      dataSource:MatTableDataSource;
      ngOnInit() {
      this.appService.getcomplains()
      .subscribe(data => this.newHero = data);
      this.dataSource = this.newHero;
      }
error :

> Type 'putDetail' is not assignable to type
>   'MatTableDataSource'.   Property '_data' is missing in type
>   'putDetail'. (property) ComplaintsComponent.dataSource:
>   MatTableDataSource

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to initialize the `dataSource` and Use `this.dataSource.data` instead of `this.dataSource` and put it inside `subscribe` call back to ensure it is only populated when your subscription is resolved not before that.

The response you get from `http` is not a JSON array but a JSON object. use **[Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values)** to convert the response into array.

```
constructor(private appService: AppService) { }
          newHero:putDetail
         dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<putDetail>();
          ngOnInit() {
          this.appService.getcomplains()
          .subscribe(data{ => this.newHero = data;
            this.dataSource.data = Object.values(this.newHero);


        });

      }
```

Comment: I still get the same error, Type 'putDetail' is not assignable to type 'putDetail[]'.
  Property 'includes' is missing in type 'putDetail'.

Comment: Share your service code if this does not work? Is your service returning Array of objects?

Comment: Service Code: getcomplains():Observable<putDetail>{
    return this.http.get<putDetail>('http://localhost:7070/api/complains');
  }

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: Yes, i have added a snap shot, please check

Comment: Did you try first approach mentioned in the answer using `Object.values`?

Comment: Glad I could help :)